# Provisioning browser extensions on Linux

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, firefox-extensions, ansible

I've always struggled with getting new Linux systems set up to my preferred specifications, and I've finally started to look into solutions for provisioning, saving dotfiles in git, etc. There's a lot of useful advice here and elsewhere on the web; I'm probably going to go with Ansible, setting up a Debian-based system.

However, I've been having trouble figuring out how to install extensions in browsers automatically; my Google-fu is failing. Basically I need to know how to install things like uBlock Origin, some proxy extension, HTTPS Everywhere, and things like that, for Chrome and Firefox (and perhaps Opera), from the command line or in some other way that I can automate via Ansible or the like, instead of having to manually visit the various stores, extension repositories, or whatever, after setting everything else up.

This is just for my personal use, to set up new machines or new VMs; I see that Google Chrome Enterprise has some facility for doing this in the corporate setting, but that's not me.

Thanks.